# Discrete mathematics and lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If X and Y are lattices then how to show that their cartesian product is also a lattice?I know that X and Y have sup. and inf. but how can I show their existance in cartesian product of X and Y?

Comment: Willing to help you on your way. Please define "$\sup$" and "$\inf$" of a subset of a poset. This will be helpful to you, in that it will tell you how to start your proof.

Comment: The infimum of a subset S of a partially ordered set P, assuming it exists, does not necessarily belong to S.

Comment: No, see, I need the *definition* of infimum. It may or may not exist, but if we are to show it  exists, we have to start with some assumptions. What would those be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show X×Y is a lattice.
You have to construct a lattice out of the other two lattices.
As a first step define (a,b) inf (x,y) as (a inf x, b inf y).